# Akka HighLevelHttp return Route from recovering Future

Tags: scala, routes, akka, future, akka-http

Because I have a request body, I need to get it as future and send the response after an action. But, I need to check if the body is valid and if is not, I want to return a BadRequest status.

I know is too much code, so please look inside the `requestFuture`, in recover function is the problem.

```
(pathPrefix("api" / "search") & post & extractRequest) { request =>
  val tokenResult = request.headers.find(x => x.name.toLowerCase == "token")
    tokenResult match {
      case None => throw new IllegalArgumentException(ServerMessages.TOKEN_NOT_FOUND)
      case Some(token) => token.value match {
        case this.apiToken => {
          val entity = request.entity
          val strictEntityFuture = entity.toStrict(2 seconds)
          val requestFuture = strictEntityFuture
              .map(_.data.utf8String.parseJson
                .convertTo[SearchFilters])

          requestFuture map { filters =>
             // here - I return an Route with data from controller
             complete(controller.searchData(filters)
               .map(_.toJson.prettyPrint)
               .map(toHttpEntity)))
          } recover (e => {
             // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
             // I need to return an Route, but here will be a Future[Route]
             complete(400 -> ServerMessages.INVALID_REQUEST_BODY)
          }
        }
        case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException(ServerMessages.INVALID_TOKEN)
      }
}
```

I need to unpack the response from the future, or to use another way to throw the error.

found a solution using `onComplete` directive, but I need to know if my json is successfully converted or not, to can throw a custom error.

```
onComplete(requestFuture) {
    case Success(filters) => searchKpi(filters) ~
       pathEndOrSingleSlash {
           complete(403 -> ServerMessages.INVALID_METHOD_ARGUMENTS)
       }
    case Failure(ex) => failWith(ex) // returns 500 Internal Server Error
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [ExceptionHandler](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/exception-handling.html).

Define your exception handler like in the doc and add a case from your exception(which should be the same that is thrown by `failWith`) to the HTTP Status you need to return (You mention `BadRequest`)

```
    case class MyBadException() extends RuntimeException

  implicit def myExceptionHandler: ExceptionHandler =
    ExceptionHandler {
      case MyBadException() => complete(HttpResponse(BadRequest)) // You decide the HTTP status to return
      case _ => complete(HttpResponse(InternalServerError, entity = "Bad numbers, bad result!!!"))
    }


    val route = path("test") {
      onComplete(getSomething()) {
        case Success(v) => complete("Ok")
        case Failure(err) => failWith(MyBadException())
      }
    }
```

Note that you have 2 ways to attach the exception handler

From the doc:

> ```
> Bring it into implicit scope at the top-level.
> Supply it as argument to the handleExceptions directive.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
val requestFuture = strictEntityFuture

requestFuture.map { entity =>
  entity.data.utf8String match {
  // Do your processing here
  case "" => RouteResult.Complete(HttpResponse(StatusCode.int2StatusCode(200), entity = HttpEntity("OK")))
}}.recover {
  case err: Throwable =>
  RouteResult.Complete(HttpResponse(StatusCode.int2StatusCode(500), entity = HttpEntity(err.getMessage)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I already had an `Exception Handle`r, but only with 2 cases (`IllegalArgument` or `NoSuchElement`). Thanks to [ccheneson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143505/ccheneson) I expanded my handler to can return a `BadRequest` response. But I'm doing something wrong there, because my `BadRequestException` is packaged to `defaultExceptionHandler` route.

[image: ExceptionHandler]

```
val routes = (
    handleExceptions(noSuchElementExceptionHandler) &
      handleExceptions(tokenNotFoundExceptionHandler)) {
    domainRoutes
  }

private val domainRoutes = {
   onComplete(future) {
      case Success(values) => complete(controller.getdata(values))
      case Failure(e) => failWith(BadRequestExceptionHandler(e.getMessage))
   }
}
```

Comment: You can do something like
`handleExceptions(noSuchElementExceptionHandler.withFallback(tokenNotFoundExceptionHandler).withFallback(defaultExceptionHandler))`